# css / jquery - add overlay to part of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wish to achive whenever an user clicks my link, only the footer will be "visible". The other content will be having an overlay.

Whenever an user presses this link, an overlay should fade in, but not on the footer #.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="enableOverlay">Enable Overlay</a>
```

The footer, which should only be visible, after the link ^ is clicked.

```
<div id="footer">
   footer text 
</div><!-- End Coming Soon -->
```

I am very confused at this point. Since I would need to have a div around all the content except the footer. This div should have the styles of my overlay - although it should also have `display:none;` which will then HIDE all the content.

What should I do, to achive this effect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naah, all you need is just [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element).

Malsup's jQuery Block UI plugin is what you need. It allows you to block whatever area you want. Also you can apply your own CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question. When the block is applied, how can I do so whenever the user just clicks a random place, the overlay is removed?

Comment: What do you mean by **random place**. Does it mean including the block area or just outside the block area?

Comment: `$('#blockarea').block({onBlock : $('*').click(function(){$('#blockarea').unblock();})` << This is if you want to unblock when user clicks anywhere (including the block area.
Else `$('#blockarea').block({bindEvents:true, onBlock : $('*').click(function(){$('#blockarea').unblock();});`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at css z-index, and then position an invisible div OVER it, not around it, with a higher z-index.

Comment: I am not sure about this. Can you please create an example. I tried, but it just hid the content with the display:none;

Comment: Did you look at my answer dude

Comment: my answer was first, so : no.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div(Transparent layer like overlay)`after the button clicked and set it's `height` to the `top` of your footer.Then when you want to close you can remove it from the page. hope this is what you are looking for....

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can be used in a practical setting. It will fade in an overlay that fades over the whole page except the footer which is taken out of normal document flow and put over the overlay.

This is necessary to keep the footer interactive/above the overlay. It will also close the overlay when clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/fxBEg/